# How to print a page in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I have a module for drupal 7 that generate reports. I want to print one of the reports with out drupal menus and footer. I want the report to be displayed on second page alone with view descriptive data? Please Help.

Comment: are you using any contributed module or using custom code to create report?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Print Module](http://drupal.org/project/print).  I've used it successfully for print media in the past.

Comment: thanks for replay.
but I want to integrate print functionality into my module rather than using other module

Comment: Lester suggested a right module. This module will provide you to add your custom page template for your print layout. You can use it with your modules as well. Using this module if any path is prefixed with "print/" it will render content in print layout. print/mymodulepage OR print/node/1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself if you really need/want to display the content on a separate page before printing it.

Providing a simple print style sheet in your theme with `display: none` for the regions that don't make sense when printed will work for all the pages on your site without the overhead of print module's approach

People that like to print things know their browser can print and will try it anyway whether you give them a print link or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Print Module](https://drupal.org/project/print). This module actually fixed the problem and performs the required functionality.